# Does Android C has better performance comparing to Java?

Tags: java, android, c, jvm

On Android [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) website you can read:

> The Android NDK is a companion tool to the Android SDK that lets you
>   build performance-critical portions of your apps in native code.
>
> ...
>
> If you write native code, your applications are still packaged into an .apk file and they still run inside of a virtual machine on the device
>
> ...
>
> Using native code does not result in an automatic performance
>   increase, but always increases application complexity.

How then can you gain on performance using C and NDK, if C is also compiled to VM code? You can bypass API, or C compiles to more optimal code, or what?

Or it is only "development speedup", so if you have some C code you dont have to port it to Java?

**Edit:**

I do **not** ask if **"Java is slower than C"**. My consideration is, if C is compiled with gcc, then how the **portability** is solved (but this is a second question, in the background)

[What are the portability implications of using the NDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116684/what-are-the-portability-implications-of-using-the-ndk)

Comment: are you really asking if C is faster than Java ??

Comment: Remember that Android has its own VM, which is a lot faster than the regular Java VM, so you only write in Java but the bytecode is Dalvik. Main reason why Blackberry apps suck and Android ones dont (Performance wise).

Comment: @CédricJulien: did I really asked it? Studying my question again revealed that I asked if Android C is run on VM, not if C is faster than Java

Comment: @JakubM. : thanks for the explanation, the title of your question could lead to misunderstanding (surely explains the 3 votes to close your question received)

Answer (score 4):

The C code that the NDK allows you to add to your app is not compiled into VM code. It is compiled using gcc and links as a shared library that can be loaded and linked via [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to Java. Therefore, you can gain performance by writing in C instead of relying on JVM optimization when writing Java code.

Comment: @JakubM: The "does not result in an automatic performance increase" is because many things you access from Java in Android are already implemented in C in the firmware, and so your own implementation may not help matters. Also, there is overhead in calling from Java into C (or vice-versa), and so a poorly-designed interface between the two may result in slower results than simply using Java for everything.

Comment: OK, so now the question that was in the background: if it is compiled via GCC, how then it can be portable? Androids run on different processors, with different instruction sets

Comment: @JakubM. : take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116684/what-are-the-portability-implications-of-using-the-ndk for the portability question.