# How to convert a jar into native code and use it instead of jar in Android Project?

Tags: android

I am using a jar file which contains an algorithm I have developed. As it is easy to decompile it, in order to prevent it, I want to convert jar into native code and use it with NDK. How to do it ?
Any other way to do it ?

Comment: You can't convert jar into native code. write the entire code in native

Comment: You have to write it in C or C++. I'm not sure what other answer you're looking from us?

Comment: Yes I will write code in C or C++. But I don't know how to use it exactly. Also java is machine independent but how will code in c behave? Do I have to have different compiled versions for different phones ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've written your algorithm in Java. You must have it in C/C++ to use NDK.

I can see only 2 options:

1. Write it from scratch in C/C++. Looking at your already written Java code it should be easy, but probably boring and time-consuming.
2. Try some Java to C++ automatic converters, for example [j2c](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/j2c/). However, sometimes they're not working, they can change the code behavior, so you need to test it all thoroughly.

Comment: Yes I will write code in C or C++. But I don't know how to use it exactly. Also java is machine independent but how will code in c behave? Do I have to have different compiled versions for different phones ?

Comment: @VipulJ For different CPU architectures - yes. Most of them are ARMs, but there are also others. [What are the portability implications of using the NDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116684/what-are-the-portability-implications-of-using-the-ndk)

Answer (score 0):

Java code obfuscation is good to improve the security of your code from reverse engineering. Try any tools like [progaurd](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#.)

Comment: I know about pro guard, but its not that effective. I want to do something native.